Maplibre Popup Styling React
Is there a solution to reduce padding in React using Maplibre Popups
<Popup
  key={point.id}
  longitude={point.geometry.coordinates[0]}
  latitude={point.geometry.coordinates[1]}
  closeButton={false}
  className="county-info"
  offset={24}
  anchor="right"
>
  <Typography style={{ fontSize: '.75rem' }}>{point?.properties?.locationName}</Typography>
</Popup>

Anything I to, it keeps default padding 15px 10px;
Kind regards
I tried different solutions of CSS stylings

Have you tried style property? style={{padding: 0}} something like that.

@Steffen yes I did, i think this is some child element but how I can access it:
there is maplibregl-popup and maplibregl-popup-content

You say you've tried different solutions, can you share some of them? That helps us narrow down what's wrong.


I did inline style
made custom Styled Component
made additional boxes/divs

